# ошибка при сборке проекта в android

Tags: android, android-studio

Неожиданно появилась ошибка при сборке нового проекта
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

кто знает, как с ней бороться?

старые проекты открываются без проблем при этом

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу код из `build.gradle` уровня app

Comment: Суппортные библиотеки должны быть одинаковой версии. В ошибке говорится, что у Вас обнаружены две зависимости (конкретно `com.android.support:support-annotations`) разных версий.

Answer (score 1):

Тестовый flavor и flavor приложения используют разные `targetSdkVersion` и(или) `compileSdkVersion` приведите их к какой-либо одной версии